# Java Applet working only on Maximized Mode

Tags: java, applet, awt

I wrote a simple Java Applet code in Eclipse. 
It is a Centimeter to Meter converter code.
It shows the result only when the Applet is in the Maximized Mode.
On minimized mode when I click Submit Button, the result is not displayed. But without changing anything in the applet if I maximize the Applet, the answer is displayed.
Why is it so?
My other codes work fine in the minimized mode.

Following is the code

```
package converter;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.applet.*;

public class convert extends Applet implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Button a;
    String msg ="";
    String msg1 = "";
    String msg2 = "";

    TextField m,n;
    Label l,p;
    float x,y;
    public void init()
    {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));
        a = new Button("Submit");
        m = new TextField(msg,10);
        n = new TextField(msg,10);
        l = new Label("IN CM");
        p = new Label("IN M");
        add(l);
        add(m);
        add(a);
        add(p);
        add(n);
        a.addActionListener(this);
        m.addActionListener(this);
        n.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
       msg1 = ae.getActionCommand();
       if(msg1.equals("Submit"))
       {
       repaint();}
    }   
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    { 
        msg2 = m.getText();     
            x = Integer.parseInt(msg2);
            y = x/100;
            msg = y + "";
            n.setText(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written logic which you want to perform on button click in paint method write that logic in `actionperformed` instead.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    msg1 = ae.getActionCommand();
    if(msg1.equals("Submit")){
       msg2 = m.getText();     
       x = Integer.parseInt(msg2);
       y = x/100;
       msg = y + "";
       n.setText(msg);
  }
}
```

Right now when you tries to resize the window paint method gets called and displays the result.

The repaint method is the way for you to explicitly call the paint method in your applet.repaint method manages the `update->paint` cycle so for the first time when you tries to repaint it calls update.You should use `repaint`  if your applet requires any resizing, scale changes,or other changes in appearance during runtime then you must include a `repaint()` to draw the applet with the changes.